# Appending json data to a table body doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, json

I'm trying to append a json data to a table body. I can append it to a div but when I try to append it ta a table nothing happens. For couple of hours I am googling for this mistake. And I saw many examples that works with same method..

Here is my javascript code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

    function getData2(id){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get.php",
            data: {id:id},
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(response)
            {
                var trHTML = '';
                $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                    trHTML +=   '<tr>' +
                                    '<td>' + item.data1 + '</td>' +
                                    '<td>' + item.data2 + '</td>' +
                                    '<td>' + item.data3 + '</td>' +
                                    '<td>' + item.data4 + '</td>' +
                                    '<td>' + item.data5 + '</td>' +
                                '</tr>';
                });

                //alert(trHTML); This Works.. I can see data in an alert
                //$('#aDiv').append(trHTML); This Works.. Appends to a div;

                //$('#tablebody').append(trHTML); Doesn't work..
                //$('#records_table tbody').append(trHTML); Doesn't work..
                $('#records_table').append(trHTML); Doesn't work..

            }
        });
    }
```

Codes for my table are:

```
<table id="records_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Head 1</th>
            <th>Head 1</th>
            <th>Head 1</th>
            <th>Head 1</th>
            <th>Head 1</th>
        </tr>   
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tablebody">
       //Json data will appear here...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, I just want to append my json data into the table body. But results of my code are

1 - With alert command I can see all data
2 - If I append it to a div I can see all data
3 - I can't append it to the table or table body...

I couldn't understand where my mistake is..

Thanks in advance to all kind people and their answers...

Comment: do you see any errors in console ?

Comment: Check that you don't have duplicate IDs

Comment: Thanks everyone. There is no errors, there aren't any duplicate IDs. And I have tried $('#records_table tbody').append(trHTML). nothing changed..

Comment: @NewGeneration How do you debug it??? Are you sure content isn't added but not just hidden? What returns: `console.log($('[id=records_table]').length);` in success callback?! Anyway, you have to provide sample replicating issue in question itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```js
var response = [{
    "data1": "1",
    "data2": "2",
    "data3": "3",
    "data4": "4",
    "data5": "5"
}];
var trHTML = '';
$.each(response, function (i, item) {
    trHTML += '<tr>' +
        '<td>' + item.data1 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + item.data2 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + item.data3 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + item.data4 + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + item.data5 + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';
});

$('#records_table > tbody').append(trHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="records_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Head 1</th>
            <th>Head 1</th>
            <th>Head 1</th>
            <th>Head 1</th>
            <th>Head 1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tablebody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: But you see my code work. I simulate the data return from ajax call.

Comment: One row from your response array seems as (data1: '1'). But in my json encode it seems as {"data1":"1","data2":"1"}.. is this a problem.. I use json_encode($variable) to create json..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ngjavacs/w5g7ahxk/ I have just created a JSFiddle. Could you please check it?

Comment: @NewGeneration: You must choose JQuery libarary (Framework and Extenstion), and call the function getData2() in script. It works.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I got it with your help.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar question on the forum,and had checked the OP's code,it lead to empty `<tr>`.

```
$.each(response, function (i, item) {

       trHTML +=   '<tr><td>' + item.data1 + '</td><td>' + item.data2 + '</td><td>' + item.data3 + '</td><td>' + item.data4 + '</td><td>' + item.data5 + '</td></tr>';
                });
```

and keep the rest of the code same.

Comment: @New Generation did it help?

Comment: @NewGeneration Can you put up a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ngjavacs/w5g7ahxk/ I I have never used JSfiddle. I hope I could.. :)

Comment: @NewGeneration It seems to be working here on my pc,check this FIDDLE link :https://jsfiddle.net/1ypx3jm7/11/

Comment: Try emptying your cache and reload perhaps? @NewGeneration

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $('#myTable > tbody:last').append(data);
```

This script working with me

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
 $('#records_table').children('tbody').append(trHTML);